# HTML button not working in Android WebView

Tags: android, html, post, webview, get

In an Android Webview I'm displaying a page with an HTML button that only works fine when it makes a GET request. This button loads a PDF document in the browser when it's working correctly.

I need this to be a POST request, however, because I was passing a lot of data in the query string, but when making a POST request nothing happens at all (on a smartphone) or the downloaded file is corrupted (on a tablet). The same button works perfectly fine when clicked on a Windows browser, whichever of GET or POST is used.

Here's the JS code and the HTML that makes the call:

```
function ExportPDF()
{
 var name = document.getElementById('lblName').innerHTML;
 var surname = document.getElementById('lblSurname').innerHTML;

 var div = '<form id="myform" method="post" action="URL"><input type="hidden" name="Name" value="'+name+'"><input type="hidden" name="Surname" value="'+surname+'"></form>';
 jQuery('#divExportPDF').append(div);
 jQuery('#myform').submit(); 
}

<button class="btnExport" onclick="ExportPDF()">EXPORT TO PDF</button>
<div id="divExportPDF"></div>
```

Comment: Is the webpage working fine in android when you are using GET?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry, updated the question now.

Comment: post your html code where you are trying to use the GET or POST. Also, is there a separate backend to this webpage which generates the PDF? Are you using any kind of library?

Comment: The PDF is generated separately, yes. We use mpdf to generate the file. I'll post some code in a mo.

Comment: If there is a backend to your web page, in PHP, add the two lines `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the PHP code and try accessing it from your android webview. See if there are any errors being shown.

Comment: Probably Android is delegating the download passing on the url requesting the download. Have you tried generating the pdf on your post request and then redirecting to a temporary file path?